# Multiple checkboxes jquery manual clicked checkbox fires, but 'code clicked' one doesn't

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have multiple checkboxes that when all are checked - they check a parent checkbox. When that parent checkbox is checked an alert is fired and an image is faded in...

**The problem is** that when the parent checkboxes are checked using jquery they do not show the alert or swap the image, *it only works when the checkbox is checked manually.*

Here is my code:
    // Parent Checkboxes -multiple checkboxes

```
$("input[type='checkbox'].PARENT-CHECKBOXES").change(function(){
    var a = $("input[type='checkbox'].PARENT-CHECKBOXES");
    if(a.length == a.filter(":checked").length){
        alert('ACTION COMPLETED');
        TweenMax.to("#fade-in-image", 0.1, {autoAlpha: 1});
    }
});

// Child Checkboxes -multiple checkboxes

$("input[type='checkbox'].CHILD-CHECKBOX").change(function(){
    var step1 = $("input[type='checkbox'].CHILD-CHECKBOX");
    if(step1.length == step1.filter(":checked").length){
        alert('SKU OPERATION COMPLETE');
        $("#PARENT-CHECKBOX1").prop("checked", true);           
    }
});
```

EDIT: So I edited my code and this is the working result.

```
var a = $("input[type='checkbox'].PARENT-CHECKBOXES");

$("input[type='checkbox'].CHILD-CHECKBOX").change(function(){
var step2 = $("input[type='checkbox'].CHILD-CHECKBOX");
if(step2.length == step2.filter(":checked").length){
        alert('Operation Complete');
        $("#PARENT-CHECKBOX1").prop("checked", true).change();
    }
if(a.length == a.filter(":checked").length){
    alert('ACTION COMPLETED');
    TweenMax.to("#fade-in-image", 0.1, {autoAlpha: 1});
}
});
```

Comment: You could call the function after you check the box programmatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you check/uncheck checkbox programmatically, it doesn't trigger automatically (as you already experienced). You need to use `.trigger()` to trigger the change event.

*code*

```
$("#PARENT-CHECKBOX1").trigger("change");
```

or

```
$("#PARENT-CHECKBOX1").change();
```

Comment: Thanks this worked - although I needed to change my code a bit to work. I've edited my post

Answer (score 2):

You need to trigger `change` event after checking - it doesn't trigger automatically - like this:

```
$("#PARENT-CHECKBOX1").prop("checked", true).trigger("change");
```